# Why can't change the permalink of my page/post?

Tags: permalinks

I'm doing this for a school project. The instructions have pictures and it says I should change the permalink under "URL Slug". However, "URL Slug" isn't anywhere on Document...

What should I do? I haven't deleted anything. I followed every instruction. I'm very new to this so please be kind...

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the page you want to update, you can modify the slug at the top above the editor:

[image]

By default Wordpress uses the Page title, but you can change the 'slug' to whatever you want.

You can also look at `Settings > Permalinks` for some more options.